# How to simulate poor scrolling

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate poor scrolling experience. This should be done by "heavy operation" function passed into scroll event listener method.

Any ideas how to create "heavy operation" function? What could that be?

Comment: Embed 50 facebook video's, it works. Personal experience.

Comment: Each time when event is fired?

Comment: I've made a site with infinite scrolling that embeds 7 new facebook videos everytime the user reaches the bottom of his screen. When the vids are loading, the scrolling stutter gets mimicked.

Answer (score 3):

This will slow down your browser heavily. If the browser is not responding at all decrease strength.

```
var i = 0;
var strength = 1000000;
clusterFuck();
function clusterFuck () {
  while(true) {
    ++i;
    document.querySelector('body');
    if(i > strength) {
      i = 0;
      setTimeout(clusterFuck, 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```